# Windows Forms application is not able to access DVD-Rom resources

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have created a desktop application that loads some files from the current path of application the program works perfectly but does not read files when it runs from DVD-Rom.

I'm using windows 8.1, and by the way I tried running the program as administrator too but I got the same result.

This is a part of my code:

```
 public void LoadTable()
        {
            if (File.Exists("table.bin"))
            {
                string[] _items = File.ReadAllLines("table.bin");
                for (int i = 0; i < _items.Length; i++)
                {
                    string[] x = _items[i].Split(',');
                    if (x.Length > 5)
                    {
                        items.Add(new Item()
                        {
                            ID=x[0].Replace("*",""),
                        ThumbStart = x[1],
                        ThumbCount= x[2],
                        PackStart = x[3],
                        PackCount = x[4]
                        });
                        List<string> _cats = new List<string>();
                        for(int j = 5;j<x.Length;j++) _cats.Add(x[j]);
                        items[items.Count - 1].Categories = _cats.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Is it something related to my code or has something windows settings?

Comment: Did you sign your compiled app?

Comment: @RowlandShaw nop can it be the problem?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I signed it but it didn't help

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "does not read files"? Do you get an exception, or it appears not to go into the for loop at all? Have you tried a tool like Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to see what the 'table.bin' I/O looks like when running from the DVD? It's possible the working directory isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @ScheuNZ I hadn't worked with Process Monitor before. When loading program I was reading 3 files (one that I have included in question and two others using filestream like: `FileStream("packs.bin", FileMode.Open)` but as the source is readonly I should have used like: `FileStream("packs.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)`. Thanks a lot for the Process monitor as I wouldn't have had a clue without it.

Comment: @ScheuNZ as your comment solved my problem, I didn't write it as answer to preserve your right to get the credit for it. If you like you can write an answer

Comment: @ScheuNZ by the way if you have time I would like to chat with you about somethig related to New Zealand

Comment: No problem, my contact email is available from my StackOverflow profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having file I/O issues, you can use Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) from the Sysinternals Suite to diagnose it. Just run the tool while you reproduce your problem and look for any failure I/O results (optionally filtering to only show I/O from your application).